# How to refactor such nested if statements?

Tags: java, logic, refactoring

I have multiple booleans in signature of the function and therefore there is multiple combinations of variants
e.g:

```
boolean deleteFile(String path, String searchName, boolean wholeWord, boolean caseSensitive) {
    
    ...

    if (caseSensitive) {
        if (wholeWord) {
            if (matchesCaseSensitively)
                return file.delete();
        } else if (containsCaseSensitively)
            return file.delete();
    } else {
        if (wholeWord) {
            if (matchesCaseInsensitively)
                return file.delete();
        } else if (containsCaseInsensitively)
            return file.delete();
    }

    return false;    
}
```

how can i get rid of nested `if` statements (maybe using boolean logic)?

EDIT: Since there are a lot of people arguing about readability the question is how to refactor it in both more readable and neat way?

Comment: Why not create a `DeleteFileRequest`, holding the parameters in an object. Then store a list of handlers, iterate through them and call them with the `DeleteFileRequest`. Each handler itself can then decide when and what it should do.

Comment: @Turing85 Could you please write some example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to have 4 different variables for matches and contains? Maybe it's possible to have only two like `matches` and `contains` which will contain the required sensitive/insensitive comparison depending on `caseSensitive` and then just `return wholeWord && matches || !wholeWord && contains ? file.delete() : false;`? We don't see the entire code but it looks like it's probably overloaded with boolean variables which can be not needed at all.

Comment: @Dornaut OK, but then two boolean varaiables will look somethisng like this

Comment: `var contains = caseSensitive ? fileName.contains(searchName) : fileName.toLowerCase().contains(searchName.toLowerCase());`
and
`var matches = caseSensitive ? fileName.matches(NameHandler.wholeWordCheck(searchName)) : fileName.toLowerCase().matches(NameHandler.wholeWordCheck(searchName.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: Then it can be even simpler. Use local variables to save fileName and searchName as source/lowercase based on caseSensitive -> then you don't need to care about `caseSensitive` in the rest code. You need only `return wholeWord && fileName.matches(NameHandler.wholeWordCheck(searchName)) || !wholeWord && fileName.contains(searchName) ? file.delete() : false;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best practices to get around nested-conditions is to flatten them into separate checks, each checking a well defined condition (which can be abstracted to a check function if it gets complicated). This approach is known as *Gateway-Style*.

So your code might look something like:

```
if ( caseSensitive &&  wholeWord && matchesCaseSensitively) return file.delete()
if ( caseSensitive && !wholeWord && containsCaseSensitively) return file.delete()
if (!caseSensitive &&  wholeWord && matchesCaseSensitively) return file.delete()
if (!caseSensitive && !wholeWord && containsCaseInsensitively) return file.delete()
```

Again, when the condition gets too complex, you might want to replace it by a checking function:

```
if (checkingFun1()) return file.delete()
```

More about Gateway-Style vs Bubble-Style here: [[Link]](https://wpshout.com/unconditionally-refactoring-nested-statements-cleaner-code/)

Answer (score 0):

That woul be less readable, so that's not a really good idea, but the come down there show how to group the conditions

---

You can group the conditions

```
boolean deleteFile(String path, String searchName, boolean wholeWord, boolean caseSensitive) {
    if (caseSensitive && ((wholeWord && matchesCaseSensitively) || containsCaseSensitively)) {
        return file.delete();
    } else if ((wholeWord && matchesCaseInsensitively) || containsCaseInsensitively) {
        return file.delete();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of even in one

```
boolean deleteFile(String path, String searchName, boolean wholeWord, boolean caseSensitive) {
    if ((caseSensitive && ((wholeWord && matchesCaseSensitively) || containsCaseSensitively)) ||
        ((wholeWord && matchesCaseInsensitively) || containsCaseInsensitively)) {
        return file.delete();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Less readable and more confusing than the OP's version IMHO.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, but that's what he asked, there is no other way of removing `if` than combining the conditions

Comment: @azro and if there will be bunch of such boolean options and more combinations can i have some logic of rewriting?

Comment: @David The logic is the boolean logic && for AND, || for OR

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent:

```
if (wholeWord && (caseSensitive && matchesCaseSensitively || !caseSensitive && matchesCaseInsensitively) ||
    !wholeWord && (caseSensitive && containsCaseSensitively || !caseSensitive && containsCaseInsensitively)) {
    return file.delete();
}
return false;
```

Although this is technically simpler (ie has less [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)), it may not be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to simplify the main flow and have their own functions to do the case sensitive and insensitive work:

```
    ...
    if (caseSensitive) {
        return deleteCaseSensitive(file, wholeWord);
    } else {
        return deleteCaseInsensitive(file, wholeWord);
    }
    ...

private boolean deleteCaseSensitive(file, wholeWord) {
    if ((wholeWord && matchesCaseSensitively) 
       || (!wholeWord && containsCaseSensitively)) {
        return file.delete();
    }
    
    return false;
}
        
private boolean deleteCaseInsensitive(file, wholeWord) {
   if ((wholeWord && matchesCaseInsensitively) 
      || (!wholeWord && containsCaseInsensitively)) {
        return file.delete();
    }

   return false;    
}
```